# Water Jug (Breadth First Traversal) - C++

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int a,b,c;

class State{
    public:
        int x,y,steps;
        State(){
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            steps = 0;
        }
};

int gcd(int a, int b){
    if(a == 0){
        return b;
    }
    if(b == 0){
        return a;
    }
    else if(a > b){
        gcd(a%b,b);
    }
    else if(b > a){
        gcd(a,b%a);
    }
}

int bfs(){
    queue<State> q;
    bool visited[a+1][b+1] = {0};
    //Start from (0,0)
    State curr = State();
    q.push(curr);
    visited[curr.x][curr.y] = true;
    //Start bfs
    while(!q.empty()){
        curr = q.front();
        q.pop();
        //Goal is reached
        if(curr.x == c || curr.y == c){
            cout<<curr.x<<" "<<curr.y<<endl;
            visited[curr.x][curr.y] = true;
            return curr.steps;
        }
        //Fill up a
        if(curr.x < a){
            State newState = State();
            newState.x = a;
            newState.y = curr.y;
            if(!visited[newState.x][newState.y]){
                newState.steps = curr.steps + 1;
                q.push(newState);
                visited[newState.x][newState.y] = true;
            }
        }
        //Fill up second jug
        if(curr.y < b){
            State newState = State();
            newState.x = curr.x;
            newState.y = b;
            if(!visited[newState.x][newState.y]){
                newState.steps = curr.steps + 1;
                q.push(newState);
                visited[newState.x][newState.y] = true;
            }
        }
        //Empty first jug
        if(curr.x > 0){
            State newState = State();
            newState.x = 0;
            newState.y = curr.y;
            if(!visited[newState.x][newState.y]){
                newState.steps = curr.steps + 1;
                q.push(newState);
                visited[newState.x][newState.y] = true;
            }
        }
        //Empty second jug
        if(curr.y > 0){
            State newState = State();
            newState.x = curr.x;
            newState.y = 0;
            if(!visited[newState.x][newState.y]){
                newState.steps = curr.steps + 1;
                q.push(newState);
                visited[newState.x][newState.y] = true;
            }
        }
        //Pour first jug into second
        if(curr.x > 0 && curr.y < b){
            State newState = State();
            newState.x = max(0, curr.x + curr.y - b);
            newState.y = min(curr.x + curr.y, b);
            if(!visited[newState.x][newState.y]){
                newState.steps = curr.steps + 1;
                q.push(newState);
                visited[newState.x][newState.y] = true;
            }
        }
        //Pour second jug into first
        if(curr.y > 0 && curr.x < a){
            State newState = State();
            newState.x = min(a, curr.x + curr.y);
            newState.y = max(0, curr.x + curr.y - a);
            if(!visited[newState.x][newState.y]){
                newState.steps = curr.steps + 1;
                q.push(newState);
                visited[newState.x][newState.y] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    for(int testcase=0; testcase<t; testcase++){
        cin>>a>>b>>c;
        //If c is a multiple of gcd(a,b) then it is solvable
        if(c % gcd(a,b) == 0 && c <= max(a,b)){
            cout<<bfs()<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<-1<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to solve the two water jugs problem, using bfs. 
I am using the following production rules, to move from one state to another,

(x, y) -> (a, y) if x < a i.e., Fill the first jug if it is not already full
(x, y) -> (x, b) if y < b i.e., Fill the second jug if it is not already full
(x, y) -> (0, y) if x > 0 i.e., Empty the first jug
(x, y) -> (x, 0) if y > 0 i.e, Empty the second jug
(x, y) -> (min(x + y, a), max(0, x + y – a)) if y > 0 i.e., Pour from second jug into first jug until the first jug is full or the second jug is empty
(x, y) -> (max(0, x + y – b), min(x + y, b)) if x > 0 i.e., Pour from first jug into second jug until the second jug is full or the first jug is empty

To be clear,
capacity of first jug = a
capacity of second jug = b
target amount of water = c

For the testcase, a = 5, b = 2, c = 3, I get the correct answer, which is 2.
For the testcase, a = 10, b = 7, c = 6, I get 0. But the correct answer is 6.

Comment: what's the problems you're dealing with?

Comment: For testcase; a = 5, b = 2, c = 3, I get the correct answer, which is 2. But for a = 10, b = 7, c = 6, I get 0. The correct answer is 6.